# Getting <Response [400]> from the TF serving api

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-requests, request, tensorflow-serving

I have trained a model to classify the leafs using TF anf TFX. I am TFServing to deploy the model in local environment. While I am been able to deploy the model but when I make a POST request to the model, It is returning <Response [400]> or `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://localhost:8501/v1/models/leaf_classification_native_keras_8/versions/1:predict`

Below is the commad to deploy the model

`docker run -p 8501:8501 --name tfserving_leaf_classification --mount  type=bind,source=/home/bhargavpatel/Desktop/Image_Classification_tfx/Image_Classification/tfx/pipelines/leaf_classification_native_keras_8/Pusher/pushed_model,target=/models/leaf_classification_native_keras_8 -e MODEL_NAME=leaf_classification_native_keras_8 -t tensorflow/serving &`

Python code to make post request

```
import base64
import io
import json

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import requests
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import pprint

SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8501/v1/models/leaf_classification_native_keras_8:predict"

IMAGE_PATH = (    "/home/bhargavpatel/Desktop/Image_Classification_tfx/Image_Classification/raw_data/test/healthy/healthy_test.0.jpg"
)

def main():
    headers = {"content-type": "serving_default"}
    img = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH, 1)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    img = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input(img)
    image_content = img.astype("uint8").tolist()
    data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": image_content})
    for _ in range(3):
        response = requests.post(SERVER_URL, json=data, headers=headers)
        pprint.pprint(response)

    total_time = 0
    num_requests = 10
    for _ in range(num_requests):
        response = requests.post(SERVER_URL, json=data, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        total_time += response.elapsed.total_seconds()
        prediction = response.json()["predictions"][0]

    print("Prediction class: {}, avg latency: {} ms".format(np.argmax(prediction), (total_time * 1000) / num_requests))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I checked wheather the docker container is reachable or not using below mentioned command

`curl http://localhost:8501/v1/models/leaf_classification_native_keras_8`

recived the below mentioned response

```
{
 "model_version_status": [
  {
   "version": "215",
   "state": "AVAILABLE",
   "status": {
    "error_code": "OK",
    "error_message": ""
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

but When i post a request for the prediction it gives the error 400 response.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try changing headers to `headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}` to define a JSON data payload. The “signature_name” in the json data is optional and can be ignored.

`img_content` needs to be updated as below.

```
image_content = img.astype('float32').to_list()
```